# Script to delete file/folder in appdata for all users from a PC List

Tags: powershell

I am having some difficulty creating a script to delete a particular file, localted in 'appdata\roaming\templates' for each user on a PC, from a PC List of about 75 PCs. Research indicted that I should create a powershell script for this, however I am fairly new to powershell. can anyone assist?

This is what I've thus far. If I run the body only, it works for the local PC.

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content .\file.txt) {
    if ($line -match $regex) {
        $users = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users"
        $users | ForEach-Object {
            Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Local\File.exe" -Force
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Being new is fine, but we'll help with code you've written and are have issue with, but not write it for you. So, show your code and the errors you are having. You'd use the Get-ChildItem and Remove-Item cmdlets for your use case. Examples are in the built-in help files.

Answer (score 1):

`Remove-Item` can work with wildcards, so you can remove the file in question from all given folders like this:

```
Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\File.exe' -Force
```

To run this command on a list of remote hosts read the list of remote hosts from a file (the file should contain one IP address or FQDN per line):

```
$servers = Get-Content 'serverlist.txt'
```

then run `Remove-Item` on the remote hosts via `Invoke-Command`:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $servers -ScriptBlock {
    Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\File.exe' -Force
}
```

Comment: nice idea the wilcard :)

Comment: The wild car is EVERY account, it may not be what they want. So be careful with that.

Comment: @RobertCotterman Quoting from the question: *"delete a particular file [...] **for each user on a PC**"* (emphasis mine).

Comment: I'm glad it works. And you want them all. My suggestion was an overall suggestion for other users that find this. Or for the future. It's a powerful thing and should always be noted with an asterisks. Pun intended

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -directory | Remove-Item -Path {("{0}\AppData\Local\File.exe" -f $_.fullname)} -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```